# Assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast in C

Tags: c

I have a problem with this. Here's the specific part of my C code:

```
unsigned char *p;
char s[1048];
int m[1048], r[2];
int e = 0, L = 0, mov = 0, ri, i;
for(*p = s; *p; ++p, mov += m[L++])
       m[L] = min(*p - 'A', 'Z' - *p + 1);
```

Now i got the message - assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast. Please help me out.

Comment: It would be useful if you tell us wich is the offending line

Comment: You actually have _two_ problem with that code. The second is the use of meaningless variable names which will make it so much harder to maintain six months from now :-)

Comment: Your code is just a mess. Why the hell do you have such an unreadable and error prone `for` statement, with abuse of side effects? Clean it up, see if your error persists, and then maybe come back again with a more detailed report of what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s` is an array of type char, you assign it to the dereferenced `p` which is a pointer of 'unsigned char'. You cannot do this without casting `s`:

The code that you probably want is:

```
for(p = (unsigned char *)s; *p; ++p, mov += m[L++])
```

by incrementing `p` in the for loop you go through all the values in the array `s`

Answer (score 4):

Change the for. Drop the `*` so you will correctly assign to a `char *`:

```
for(*p = s; *p; ++p, mov += m[L++])
    ^
```

Comment: Exactly: you're using the 'p' pointer to iterate through the 's' array: you start at the start of 's' (p = s), move the pointer one to the right every iteration (++p) until you reach a null pointer ('*p' becomes false).

Answer (score 2):

*p i an unsigned char (deferencing a pointer to an unsigned char).

s is a pointer to a char (since it's an array).

So you're assigning a pointer to an unsigned char.

I would assume the compiler is saying that because you're making a char from a pointer without a cast.